# Toggle settings with hashtags, PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP application that receives incoming SMS messages via Twilio and changes user preferences based on a hashtag and setting. For example, if a user wanted to disable SMS alerts from the site, they would text `#sms off`.

Below is the code that I have put together to handle this task but I feel that it is bloated and could be cleaned up a bit. Any suggestions on how to approach this task from another (hopefully neater) angle would be appreciated.

It's tricky because the incoming hashtag could be in any cAsE - `#SMS off`, `#Sms Off`, etc. I deal with this by making both the command and setting uppercase.

Here is what I have so far -

```
<?php
$body = trim($_POST['Body']);
$pos = strripos($body, '#'); //Find position of hashtag in body
if ($pos != 0) {
    //Hashtag was not first, therefor this is a normal incoming SMS
    //without commands
    echo "Normal SMS message";
} else if ($pos == 0) {
    //This is a command SMS, we need to react to it
    preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$body,$matches); // Isolate the hashtag
    // Change hashtag, complete with #, to uppercase
    //This is to prevent case issues in the incoming SMS
    $command = strtoupper($matches[0][0]);
    //Remove the hashtag from the SMS, convert the remaining string to upper,
    //and trim it to isolate
    $setting = str_ireplace($command, '', $body);
    $setting = strtoupper(trim($setting));
    //Switch for available commands
    switch ($command) {
        case '#DISPATCH':
            if ($setting == 'ON') {
                echo 'Dispatch alert has been turned on';
            } else if ($setting == 'OFF') {
                echo 'Dispatch alert has been turned off';
            } else {
                'Missing setting. Please reply with #dispatch on or #dispatch off to set.';
            }
            break;
        case '#SMS':
            if ($setting == 'ON') {
                echo 'SMS alerts have been turned on';
            } else if ($setting == 'OFF') {
                echo 'SMS alerts have been turned off';
            } else {
                'Missing setting. Please reply with #sms on or #sms off to set.';
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo 'I do not recognize this command. Please enter either #dispatch or #sms followed by on or off to set.';
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that `explode()` is a bit easier to use. Something like this (untested):

```
$pos = strripos($body, '#'); //Find position of hashtag in body
if ($pos != 0) {
    echo "Normal SMS message";
} else {
    // The input needs to be all uppercase, and split apart by the space
    $pieces = explode(" ",strtoupper($body));

    // Our command will be the first item
    $command = array_shift($pieces);
    // The rest will be the setting
    $setting = trim(implode(" ",$pieces));

    switch($command) {

    ...
```

Comment: I like it apart from one drawback - if there is more than one space following the hashtag, the setting is not included

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. It's easy to grab the first array element as the command, then stitch it back together. I just find that working with arrays are a ton easier than string manipulation, in general.

Comment: Going with this for now, thanks! Seems to be working fine, deployed :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do a more object-oriented approach.

For example the code could look like this:

```
$sms = new SMS($_POST['Body']);
```

SMS would be responsible for parsing everything and abstracting away anything about that.

```
if ($sms->hasCommand()) {
    $commandDispatcher = new SMSCommandDispatcher($sms->getCommand(), $sms->getCommandArguments());
    $commandDispatcher->dispatch();
}
```

SMSCommandDispatcher would know which commands exist and execute them:

it could look like this:

```
class SMSCommandDispatcher {
    protected $knownCommands = array(
        'dispatch' => 'DispatchCommand',
        'sms' => 'SMSCommand',
    );

    public function __construct($cmd, $args) {
        if (!isset($this->knownCommands[$cmd])) throw new InvalidArgumentException('Unknown command');
        $this->commandInstance = new $this->knownCommands[$cmd]($args);
    }

    public function dispatch() {
        $this->commandInstance->invoke();
    }
}
```

Then you have the classes SMSCommand and DispatchCommand of course...

Abstraction is very helpful getting rid of bloat. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along the same lines in terms of OOP - this is actually all part of an existing class and it will be split up into different methods. The code posted in my question is a more simplistic version of the problem. The core issue is the best way to find a hashtag at the beginning (won't always be hashtags) of the message and then split the command and setting

Comment: I think you should do the refactoring and abstraction first and then thinking of "good" ways for solving the low-level problems - when you have such an abstraction you can add support for all kinds of method and argument types by only changing very small parts of your code, best would be even if you only have to add classes for this and do not have to edit existing classes. Of course I don't know what you already have so I can only hope I could help you :)

Comment: This is part of a pretty expansive Laravel project. The class in question is a mess, for sure. I'm working on modularizing it some more and will revisit. +1 for OOP approach